# Unexpected Token Export: Controller

Tags: node.js

I am writing a controller for my routes file in node js

Here is my code for the controller

```
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler')
const Product = require('../models/productModel')

// @desc Fetch All Products
// @route GET /api/products
// @access Public
const getProducts = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const products = await Product.find({});
  res.json(products);
});

// @desc Fetch Product By Id (single product)
// @route GET /api/products/:id
// @access Public
const getProductById = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);

  if (product) {
    res.json(product);
  } else {
    res.status(404);
    throw new Error("Product Not Found");
  }
});

export {getProductById, getProducts}
```

however it is giving me an error of for the last line of the code, saying SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Comment: shouldn't it be module.exports={getProductById, getProducts}

Comment: yes ... thank you.. idk why node js doesnt accept es6.. its really frustrating sometimes switching between front and back end code writing

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get `export` going is to rename your files from `.js` to `.mjs`.